# Context menu on a WinForms control in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf-controls

I have the need of a chart/graph control in a WPF application, and I have managed to use the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting via .

I would like to have a context menu for the chart, and I would like to have the context menu done in WPF so I wont have to do a WinForms control that wraps the Chart and adds a context menu.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this for a web application or a winforms / wpf standalone executable?

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341747/contextmenu-on-windowsformshost-control and implemented a similar solution and it works.