# Add new contextmenu items to WindowsFormsHost which has default ContextMenu in WPF

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, windowsformshost

We are using some ActiveX or windows form control which don't have the WPF equivalences, so naturally we use WindowsFormsHost to host these controls. We normally make an UserControl out of it with some general controls such as button to implement the common functionality. One piece of xaml code is something like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" >   
    <WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>                    
            <MenuItem Header="_Test1" />
        </ContextMenu>                    
    </WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu>

    <AxOWC:AxPivotTable x:Name="pivotTable" />        
</WindowsFormsHost>        
....
```

The AxPivotTable is a OWC (office web component) control. In another UserControl, we add a ReportViewer inside the WindowsFormsHost. Note that normally the AxPivotTable or ReportViewer has its default context menu even without any ContextMenu item I add.

So far my customized ContextMenu doesn't get showed yet (still the default one shows). Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341747/contextmenu-on-windowsformshost-control), I figured out I still need to capture the the mouse down event in the code-behind and set

```
windowsFormsHost1.ContextMenu.IsOpen = True
```

to show the contextmenu (weird though).

Now my problem is, only this Test1 ContextMenu is here now. The default ContextMenu won't show any more. As I mentioned, what we want is to add the customized on top of those default context menus.

Comment: are you able to dive in your `windowsFormsHost1` to get the `ContextMenu` object? so you could do `_yourContextMenu_.Items.Add(newMenuItem)`

Comment: @WiiMaxx ,that's actually the part I don't understand. In my event handler where I set I set IsOpen=True, I can see the ContextMenu actually only contains my customized items, not the default menu provided by the control themselves. So I don't know how I can get these default menus so I can't add them(since the control are not in WPF assemblies I don't even know whether I can just use Items.Add to add them without conversion). In another word, my customized CM will overwrite the default since they are on different levels, and only if I don't have any customized one the default will be popped.

Answer (score 0):

this would be my working "Solution" for your example above i don't know if you need this also for Child Elements from your `WindowsFormsHost`. Hope this will help you

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tete.MainWindow"
        xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
    <Grid>
        <av:WindowsFormsHost Name="myWFH">
            <wf:ComboBox Name="myCBox">
            <wf:ComboBox.ContextMenu>
                <wf:ContextMenu>
                    <wf:ContextMenu.MenuItems>
                        <wf:MenuItem Text="somet"/>
                    </wf:ContextMenu.MenuItems>
                </wf:ContextMenu>
            </wf:ComboBox.ContextMenu>
        </wf:ComboBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Code-Behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace tete
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        var child = myWFH.Child as System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;
        child.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem("my new menuitem"));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
i hope now it fit's your needs :) and i understand correctly what you want ToDo

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what the problem you are trying to solve with this code? It might be that I didn't describe my question clearly. The AxOWC:AxPivotTable (and other WinForms control we wrap inside WindowsFormsHost)has its default ContextMenu, which is of type System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu, not of WPF type. But now I want to make my customized context menu items coexist with the default, so the user has an enhanced context menu. But with my code from the question, the customized menu will overwrite/shadow the default context menu, which is not what I want.

Comment: oh it looks like i miss this part :o) i will dig a bit on this

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Just a few words about the results: I use myWFH.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true in an event handler of mouse down event, and you do that in the constructor. Your code basically does the similar thing as my post except one thing: if I run your code, the customized context menu will show up once when the UserControl/Window is constructed, still shadowing the default one, and later when I right click the default context menu show again shadowing the customized one. On the contrary, my code always shadows the default context menu. Neither way produces desired result

Comment: @tete i hope now it's what you need if it doesn't fit cloud you please tell me what assembly `AxOWC` is so i could dig deeper ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still have some issue with the controls, but I'll come back to you later.

Comment: WiiMaxx, I still can't figure it out. You example differs at least in one fact: the wf:ComboBox doesn't have an integrated context menu anyway. So when you add one item in xaml and others in code-behind, everything is under your control and you know for sure they will be displayed together. But the controls I use, for example, Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer, the control itself has a context menu and it is really mysterious where I can find this context menu object and add my customized there. For example, if I follow your routine to have Dim child = windowsFormsHost1.Child.

Comment: I can see child.ContextMenu.MenuItems has actually ZERO count collection, which means the default context menu doesn't exist on this level. And therefore adding a new menu item on this level can't make it appear with the default context menu. In fact, the one I added to the MenuItems won't be displayed at all, still only the default context menu, which I have ABSOLUTELY no idea where comes from, is displayed

Comment: @tete after Lunch i will take a look on it maybe i can figure it out :)

Comment: @tete ok i could narrow down your problem (on the `ReportViewer` example)  i looks like the `ContextMenu` that already exist is connect to an `Child-Element` and not on the `ReportViewer-Element` itself. But i'm not able to figure out which Element is the one who contains the `ContextMenu`

Comment: Thank you again for your information. But Child of whom? The windowsFormsHost1.Child is the ReportViewer itself. And the ReportViewer object doesn't have a member called Child

Comment: @tele surly it doesn't contains such a property but it still contains Elemments for e.g in `Controls` (but there is only a ..Spliter that does nothing as far as i can say) so ther must be an other element which contains your ContextMenu you should search/build a method(would recoment extension) that finds **all** Child-Elements by type and with some look you will get what you need and then you can bubble up to be able to add your stuff